# Open terminal before running sendSequence in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a shortcut with this command

```
 {
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "when": "terminalFocus",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": {
      "text": #command#
    }
 },
```

And before running it I want to open a integrated terminal window and then send the sequence and run the code - and keep the terminal open afterwards, the shortcut should also not open a terminal if one is already running. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a macro extension to run two commands: getting the terminal and writing to it.  Using the extension [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) try this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+q",
  "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
  "args": {
    "sequence": [
      "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
      {
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": "${fileBasename}"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you do not have a terminal open, it should open one and focus it.  If you do have a terminal open it should focus that terminal.